# Boosting current on Genuino MKR1000 digital pin output

Tags: arduino, solid-state-relay

I am trying to switch on a G5Q Relay on a Genuino MKR1000. 
I am able to do it using VCC (3.3v) but not with Digital I/O pin (Also 3.3v) this is because the current from digital pin is lower(7mA). I am new to electronics. How can I boost the current to the relay without damaging my board?

Comment: Check sources like Aliexpress and buy a relay module.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/203906/9006 Also, web search engines provide a lot of results by searching for "controlling relay with arduino". There are also likely answers on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/ Please read the [help] to understand how to ask good questions. This question will likely get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I increase the drive current from the arduino digital pins?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/203903/how-do-i-increase-the-drive-current-from-the-arduino-digital-pins)

Comment: Possible duplicate of a hundred questions. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is mostly a duplicate of "[How do I increase the drive current from the arduino digital pins?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/203903/)" as kindly commented already, there is another point to address in your question.

You said:

> I am trying to switch on a G5Q Relay on a Genuino MKR1000. I am able to do it using VCC (3.3v)

The lowest coil voltage [G5Q relay](https://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5q.pdf) has a nominal 5V coil - not 3.3V. The fact that yours operates at 3.3V is not guaranteed and will be affected by things including temperature, internal wear etc. The G5Q datasheet I linked above shows that Omron guarantee the relay will operate at 75% of nominal coil voltage = 3.75V for a 5V coil. Therefore, as I said, your relay is not guaranteed to operate at 3.3V.

You may also find this previous question interesting, about operating relays at reduced voltages: "[Is it OK to use a lower voltage to operate a relay coil than rated coil voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/207723/)"

Therefore your situation seems to require:

- an suitable external driver (e.g. transistor) and freewheeling diode, to drive the relay coil (see the [first linked question above](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/203903/)) from the 3.3V digital output of your board; and
- a suitable power supply voltage for your relay.

  That means using a 5V supply for a 5V relay, if you expect reliable operation. From researching your [MKR1000 board](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMKR1000), I see that 5V is available when the board is powered via its USB or Vin connectors. This could be used to supply a 5V relay coil (assuming a suitable current rating of that power supply). Don't use the 3.3V supply which you mentioned, to directly power a 5V relay.

  However when the board is powered from an attached LiPo battery, then only the 3.3V supply voltage is available. A boost regulator could be added to generate 5V from that 3.3V input, and the generated 5V could be used to power a 5V relay. I could not find documentation stating how much current your board can supply at 3.3V (to power a 5V boost regulator and relay) in that situation. The answer will be related to the 3.3V regulator IC ([AP7215-33YG](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/AP7215.pdf), according to the [board schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/MKR1000-schematic.pdf)) and how much current the board already uses, from the 600mA maximum which that regulator can supply according to its datasheet.

So in summary: The way forward depends on how you intend to power your board. I just wanted to highlight that powering a 5V relay from 3.3V (even when you think it works, as you stated) can result in problems.

Comment: IO pin supplies 7mA at 3.3v while the relay takes 30mA at 5v

Comment: @Kashif - "IO pin supplies 7mA at 3.3v while the relay takes 30mA at 5v" - That difference in *current* required vs. available directly from the pin, is why you need to use an external driver (e.g. BJT, MOSFET etc.). (FYI the relay's rated current is *40mA* @ 5V according to the datasheet I linked.) You should never try to power a relay *directly* from an I/O pin. How to handle the difference in *voltage* is what I tried to explain in my answer. Again, the voltage at the I/O pin is only part of the story (you don't power a relay from an I/O pin!); it is the power supply voltage which matters.

Comment: [continued] If you have a specific question about something which is not clear, please ask it.